# Beginner JavaScript - restarting my for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have an animation running in 4 steps, when the 4 steps are over, I would like it to restart.

```
var aSteps = [
    {
        "x": "800",
        "y": "0"
    },
    {
        "x": "800",
        "y": "500"
    },
    {
        "x": "0",
        "y": "500"
    }, {
        "x": "0",
        "y": "0"
    }
];

var iStepsLength = aSteps.length;
for (var i = 0; i < iStepsLength; i++) 
{
    $('#P1').animate
    ({
        left: aSteps[i].x,
        top: aSteps[i].y,
     }, 1000);
}
```

I've tried to add an if statement like.

```
if (i == 3)
{
    i=0;    
}
```

But then my browser will just crash because it runs the for loop infinitely. I hope that you can help me out, and teach me what it is that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You need `window.setTimeout`

Comment: Use setInterval or setTimeout to call your function with periodic interval. Don't call the animate method in for loop.

Comment: Being that jquery is being used I think the callback is a tidier solution than setting up timers. Timers can be beneficial though if there are lots of objects all animated at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) can take a callback which will be invoked when the animation has ended:

```
function animateSteps( counter ) {
    $('#P1').animate({
        left: aSteps[ counter ].x,
        top: aSteps[ counter ].y,
     }, 1000, function(){
         if (counter == 3)
         {
            counter=0;    
         }
         animateSteps( counter + 1 );
     });
}

animateSteps( 0 );
```

Answer (score -1):

set the for loop equal to a function. call the function, then call it again. 
EDIT:
Like this:

```
function forloop() { 
   for (var i = 0; i < iStepsLength; i++) {
     $('#P1').animate ({ left: aSteps[i].x, top: aSteps[i].y, }, 1000); 
   }
}
```

then you can just call the function whenever you want the loop to run like so:

forloop()

Comment: Sounds like a recipe for disaster?! Maybe you'd like to explain that a bit clearer.

Comment: ...ok so you've clarified your thinking a bit, but even so, how then do you know when to call the function without ending up in the same situation as you had originally (infinite loop)? You might as well just utilise the built in callback facility of the animate command and avoid the for loop altogether.

Comment: maybe im not understanding the question, but I figured that since the loop would run until i equaled the length of the way, it would only run 4 times. If OP wanted the loop to run again, then they could just call the loop again. No infinite loop, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: What the OP wanted was the loop to run again as soon as the last animation had finished (or even when i == 3), the problem is there is nothing to stop the loop doing that in a nanosecond. What you have done is simply put the loop into a function. The problem is knowing when to call that function ... doing it your way how do you know when you've reached the end of the first four animation steps? Where do you put the check for i == iStepsLength that won't cause it to do what it did originally (basically causing a sort of infinite loop).

Comment: You need to remember that he animate function is asynchronous so the loop doesn't wait for the animation to complete. That may be what you are missing here.

Comment: my bad. i assumed that you could just call the function twice, one after another, and it would only do the second once the first had finished. i thought wrong...

Comment: no worries, we all make mistakes ... all part of the learning process! gurvinder372's answer is the best way to approach this problem as once you are using asynchronous code it makes a lot of sense to use events/callbacks to get a grip on things.

Comment: speaking of not understanding javascript, perhaps you could take a look at this for me because I'm curious why the onclick event for the second button is not working. https://github.com/macsplean/odin2_boxmaker ......   http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/macsplean/odin2_boxmaker/blob/master/index.html

Comment: Shouldn't really hijack this thread ... maybe add that one to a new question? I can't see anything immediately wrong with what you've done though.